# gnu mcu eclipse can't associate device with project

Tags: eclipse, arm

I'm trying to get started with GNU MCU eclipse following the resources on their git hub site.

I'm trying to get blinky running am struggling to assign a device.

In project properties->devices I see "No devices available, install xPacks or CMSIS packs first".

I try to do that following these instructions: https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/plugins/packs-manager/

Which tell me that the CMSIS packs are already installed.

However, the packs view then doesn't load.

Any idea where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem ended up being creating a new eclipse workspace. Why this worked, I don't know. Presumably some corruption or initialisation issue with the default workspace.

From a new workspace I was able to launch the packs perspective and refresh - as described by Jacob.

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to switch to "Packs" perspective in your GNU MCU Eclipse (Window -> Perspective -> Open Perspective -> Other ... -> Packs).
2. Then there is a "Packs" tab in the editor area. Click on "refresh" button, all the packs will be downloaded automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd tried point 1 many times as I hope I'd explained in the question. Point 2 was very useful when I finally got this working.